# Is it possible to do "Europe" -> "SFO" kind of search for airline tickets?

Tags: flight-search-engines

We know that you can do flexible search for multiple destinations for a specific date with a fixed source airport. For example, if you want to fly somewhere for a weekend from London, but don't care where exactly and want to see the prices, you can use either Google Flights or SkyScanner, type "Europe" as a destination and see the possible destinations and prices.

Is it possible to do the same search with fixed destination airport? What I mean is that I want to be in Heathrow on 1st, and I want to know from which airport around Europe it would be the cheapest to fly there on this particular date? So kind of "Europe" - > "LHR" search?

Edit: I know it is possible to do broad search from a source airport to multiple destinations. However **I'm looking for the opposite - a search from many origins spawning multiple countries to one specific destination airport**.

To be very specific: I want to type in "Europe" into the origin (not the "list of a few airports)", and "SFO" into the destination (not the "USA"), and see the flights with prices for the particular date.

Neither Kayar, nor ITA Matrix, nor Skyscanner, nor Google Flights seem to allow that.

Comment: You can certainly do "Country" to destination on skyscanner

Comment: Europe is really quite large. I'm not sure that such a search would make sense in a lot of cases.

Comment: It does for me - I can fly return whichever way I want, but I'm restricted by price. So if Copenhagen - SFO has the cheapest price, and I can get to Copenhagen by train relatively cheap, I'd fly that.

Comment: @Karlson, I already know that. I need to enter "Multiple Counties" as **origin**, and the destination is a fixed airport.

Comment: ITA Matrix allows for searching from [all airports within a radius](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rFGPb.png) (e.g. 500 miles) of a starting point.

Comment: @GeorgeY. I think what Michael Hampton is trying to say is that if you can get to Copenhagen with relatively low cost in time and inconvenience then it's unlikely you can also get to Lisbon and Athens and Dublin with relatively low cost in time and inconvenience.

Comment: @phoog I suppose it depends on how well you can tolerate Ryanair.

Comment: It's true that most broad search tools (Sky Scanner, Adioso…) have more flexibility in the destination than in the origin. ITA Matrix comes pretty close though, you can't type in "Europe" and have to go through the trouble of typing in airport codes yourself but it can cope with more than a few: For example, I could search for trips between "AMS, GVA, CDG, FRA, FCO, MAD" and "SFO" and even got open-jaw tickets like CDG-MEX-SFO-MEX-MAD, which seems pretty powerful.

Comment: So if you create a list of the main intercontinental airports in the area you are interested it, you can already do a search that's probably too broad for your own good ;) An additional benefit is that this solution is broad yet flexible: you could add Istanbul and ignore Helsinki, etc.

Comment: @phoog convenience is not part of this equation. However if I know I can fly cheap on Mon from Lisboa, I might find a cheap way to get to Lisboa before Mon - I don't have to be there exactly on Mon, might get in on Fri.

Comment: @Relaxed that would be too restrictive, because someone like Air Berlin might fly this route as OTP-TXL-FRA-SFO and price it way cheaper than FRA-SFO (they have done that before) - and OTP is certainly not a major intercontinental hub. Kiwi however seem to do what I need, just going to see how accurate it is on the routes I already know well.

Comment: KEF, MAN, CPH, DUB, LHR, AMS, TXL, DUS, FRA, MUC, CDG, ZRH, IST are the only European airports accessible from SFO and IST is a stretch. You can add TLV, AUH and DXB if you want to stretch it even more. But that's it.

Comment: I'm ok with connecting flights (such as SFO-ATL-X or SFO-SEA-X) if it helps saving significant amount of money. In fact I prefer them, as those flights tend to be less full than long-distance SFO flights.